# How to detect changes in the asp panel through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik

I have many controls(like texbox,telerik grid, dropdown and radio button) on one asp panel.Could someone help me in detecting changes in any control of asp panel while clicking submit button.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: CAn you show us what you have tried to do?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way of doing this, but my suggestion would be:

Create a hidden field that has a default value of "False". This hidden field will tell us if the form has changed or not.
Then assigning any editable control the JavaScript `OnChange` event. 
The `OnChange` event should call a simple method that sets the value of the hidden field to "True".
For example with jQuery it would be:

```
function FormChanged() {
    $(".hiddenField").val("True");
}
```

Then when you submit you will be able to access the value of the hidden field to know wether the form has benn changed or not.